# Samsung X-Cover USB Debugging not turning on

Tags: usb-debugging

I just tried to root a friend's Samsung XCover, first connected it to the PC, windows recognized it and installed some drivers, then I turned on USB Debug and there was no indication it wasn't turning it on, neither the phone showed, nor the PC tried to install some drivers, BUT it was still connected as a media device.... What could be wrong?

Comment: You forgot to disconnect and re-connect the device? Correct order: 1) disconnect the cable, 2) enable USB-Debugging, 3) re-connect.

Comment: Do you have the latest drivers of the device installed on your PC?

Comment: I reconected it several times, still no indication that the USB debug was turned on...